# Custom datasets in Watson Q&A service

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

Is there a way to create a custom dataset in Watson for use with services such as Question and Answer?

I tried the service using the 'healthcare' dataset and it was very limited. I could ask it any of the questions that were suggested by the IBM team (ex. What is HIV?) and get satisfactory results but straying from that list produced unreliable results. For example I asked it 'How can I lower my blood sugar' and none of the results even mentioned blood sugar. This makes me wonder how in-depth the healthcare dataset is and if there is a way we can add to it or create new datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the service is in BETA, there is no way to bring a custom corpus (dataset). This feature is being planned and should be available soon.

Comment: Thank you. Its hard to really gauge how useful Watson Q&A is (for example) without the ability to expand on the knowledgebase we can use - the healthcare example is VERY limited...

Comment: any idea when this is scheduled for release?